# Fetching asynchronous results from database in loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, asynchronous, express

First i have to fetch the posts from database and then loop through it to get its comments and again i have to loop through every comments to get it likes!here now i am facing problem as i am fetching likes from database which goes asynchronous ! is there a way so that i can wait until every database records has been fetched and then i can response the data?

here is my code

```
  attachCommentsLikes: function(req, res, next) {
            if(req.cdata.success === 0) return next();

            var cmnt = _.pluck(req.cdata.message.data, 'comments');
            var postsComment = [];
            _.forEach(cmnt, function(item, index) {
                postsComment[index] = _.pluck(item, 'id');
            });

            async.forEachOf(postsComment, function(item, index, cb) {
                anydb(req.user.database, 'discussion_comments_likes').inn({
                    data: item,
                    where: "comment_id"
                }, function(error, result) {

                    item.forEach(function(commentId, indexOfCommentId) {

                        var likes = _.where(result, {
                            comment_id: commentId,
                            status: 1
                        }).length;
                        req.cdata.message.data.forEach(function(current, indexOfPosts) {
                            var indexOfComment = _.findIndex(current.comments, function(chr) {
                                return chr.id === commentId;
                            });
                            if (indexOfComment != -1) {
                                req.cdata.message.data[indexOfPosts].comments[indexOfComment].likes = likes;
                                if (_.where(result, {
                                    comment_id: commentId,
                                    status: 1,
                                    liked_by: req.user.id
                                }).length) {
                                    req.cdata.message.data[indexOfPosts].comments[indexOfComment].liked = 1;
                                }
                            }
                        });


                    });

                    if ((postsComment.length - 1) === index) {
                        console.log(req.cdata.message.data)
                        next();
                    }
                });

            }, function(item) {

            });
            // next();
        },
```

**Update:** i solved this problem by concating all comments id's in one array and fetched it one query instead of looping for every id's using sql's in function

```
var allIds = [];
            _.forEach(postsComment, function(item, index) {
                _.forEach(item, function(current) {
                    allIds.push(current);
                });
            });
```

Comment: can't you fetch all the data in one go?  if not, you can build up a bunch of `promise`'s and then wait for them all to be done (but I'd suggest not to do so many queries, rather do one query to get all that data).

Comment: I have 3 tables for posts,comments, and likes so what i am doing is first taking id's of posts and getting comments of related posts and getting every comments id's and fetching likes of every  comments ..

Comment: That's pretty much what JOIN statements are for in sql. Alternatively you could use something like the [Async module](https://github.com/caolan/async) for asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: while using async module all the database request goes async and then the final callback receive nothing as all request are async